# Display Customer total spent without shipping in Woocommerce

Tags: php, sql, wordpress, woocommerce, orders

I'm trying to show how much each customer has spent in total WITHOUT including the shipping cost. Everything from the code below, which creates a new column and makes it sortable, works fine except for the calculation.

I get an error on line 37 which is this one:

```
$money_spent = wc_get_customer_total_spent( $user_id ) - $order->get_total_tax() - $order->get_total_shipping() - $order->get_shipping_tax(), wc_get_price_decimals(), '.', '' );
```

Here is all the code I'm using =>

```
class Total_Spent_By_Customer_WooCommerce {

    public function __construct() {
        add_action( 'init', array( &$this, 'init' ) );
    }

    public function init() {
    add_filter( 'manage_users_columns', array( $this,'users_columns') );
    add_action( 'manage_users_custom_column',  array( $this ,'users_custom_column'), 10, 3);
    add_filter( 'manage_users_sortable_columns', array( $this ,'users_sortable_columns') );
    add_filter( 'users_list_table_query_args', array( $this ,'users_orderby_column'), 10, 1 );
    add_action( 'plugins_loaded', array( $this ,'load_this_textdomain') );
  }

  public static function users_columns( $columns ) {
    unset($columns['posts']);
    $columns['money_spent'] = _x( 'Money Spent', 'user', 'total-spent-by-customer-for-woocommerce' );
    return $columns;
  }

  public static function users_custom_column( $value, $column_name, $user_id ) {
    if ( 'money_spent' != $column_name ) {
      return $value;
    } else {
      $money_spent = wc_get_customer_total_spent( $user_id ) - $order->get_total_tax() - $order->get_total_shipping() - $order->get_shipping_tax(), wc_get_price_decimals(), '.', '' );
      return wc_price( wc_get_customer_total_spent ( $user_id ));
    }
  }

  public static function users_sortable_columns($columns) {
    $custom = array(
      'money_spent'    => 'money_spent',
    );

    return wp_parse_args( $custom, $columns );
  }

  public static function users_orderby_column( $args ) {
    if ( isset( $args['orderby'] ) && 'money_spent' == $args['orderby'] ) {
      $args = array_merge( $args, array(
        'meta_key' => '_money_spent',
        'orderby'    => 'meta_value_num',
      ));
    }

    return $args;
  }

  public function load_this_textdomain() {
    load_plugin_textdomain( 'total-spent-by-customer-for-woocommerce' );
  }
}

new Total_Spent_By_Customer_WooCommerce();
```

I would really appreciate any type of help with this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Update 2**

You **can not get Customer total spent without shipping and taxes totals** using `wc_get_customer_total_spent( $user_id )` function, as you should need to remove the taxes and shipping for each order that the current customer has made.

Also you can not get and use The `WC_Order` object in your function. So the  `WC_Order` methods `get_total_tax()`, `get_total_shipping()` and `get_shipping_tax()` can't be used.

---

**The alternative** to get the customer total spent without shipping and taxes:

Based on [the SQL Woocommerce query source code](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/source-class-WC_Customer_Data_Store.html#336-368) involved in `wc_get_customer_total_spent()` function we can build your own query.

So you will replace your function by this:

```
public static function users_custom_column( $value, $column_name, $user_id ) {
    if ( 'money_spent' == $column_name ) {
        global $wpdb;

        $statuses = array_map( 'esc_sql', wc_get_is_paid_statuses() );
        
        $spent    = $wpdb->get_var("
            SELECT SUM(pm2.meta_value - (pm3.meta_value + pm4.meta_value))
            FROM $wpdb->posts as p
            LEFT JOIN {$wpdb->postmeta} AS pm ON p.ID = pm.post_id
            LEFT JOIN {$wpdb->postmeta} AS pm2 ON p.ID = pm2.post_id
            LEFT JOIN {$wpdb->postmeta} AS pm3 ON p.ID = pm3.post_id
            LEFT JOIN {$wpdb->postmeta} AS pm4 ON p.ID = pm4.post_id
            WHERE   pm.meta_key   = '_customer_user'
            AND     pm.meta_value = '" . esc_sql( $user_id ) . "'
            AND     p.post_type   = 'shop_order'
            AND     p.post_status IN ( 'wc-" . implode( "','wc-", $statuses ) . "' )
            AND     pm2.meta_key  = '_order_total'
            AND     pm3.meta_key  = '_order_tax'
            AND     pm4.meta_key  = '_order_shipping'
        ");

        if ( ! $spent ) {
            $spent = 0;
        }
        $value = wc_price( $spent );
    }
    return $value;
}
```

Tested and perfectly works.

> **Calculations note:**
>
> As you are removing the total taxes from the orders you don't need to remove the shipping taxes (as they are included in the total taxes).
>
> So we just remove the total taxes and the total shipping (excluding taxes).

Comment: Using the new function from you results in a fatal error. Removing one ) from the end makes the site work again but gives this error: Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function get_total_tax()

Comment: Yes, I noticed that. The function from the beginning is this:

  public static function users_custom_column( $value, $column_name, $user_id ) {
    if ( 'money_spent' != $column_name ) {
      return $value;
    } else {
      $money_spent = wc_get_customer_total_spent( $user_id );
      return wc_price( wc_get_customer_total_spent ( $user_id ));
    }
  }

But it shows the shipping. Tax is fine, it's shipping that needs to be removed from the equation.

Comment: @WooDevil OK I have found the way and updated my answer.

Comment: Thank you! I just removed pm3.meta_value from SELECT SUM(pm2.meta_value - (pm3.meta_value + pm4.meta_value)) to get the sum without shipping. Thanks a lot!!